# React container component

Tags: ecmascript-6, react.js, jsx

This is my first reactJS project and I am trying to build a page out of my components. I thought it would be best to create a section component and then put appropriate components inside of it.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way... it works but looks a bit weird when there is more than one component. Also VS Code yells at me if I put an apostrophe in a heading.

#### MySection.js

```
        <section className={this.props.bgColor + " USBSection">
          <div className="container">
            {this.props.content}
          </div>
         </section>
```

#### Homepage.js

```
      <MySection
        bgColor={'bg-gray'}
        content={
          [
            <MediaObject heading={'today's rates!'} />,
            <MediaObject heading={'some other heading'} />,
            <MediaObject heading={'other other heading'} />
           ] />

      <MySection
        bgColor={'bg-gray'}
        content={
            <MediaObject heading={'today's rates!'} />,
        } />
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to put content as a prop, you can do this:

```
<section className={this.props.bgColor + " USBSection">
   <div className="container">{this.props.children}</div>
</section>
```

and then you can use your component as:

```
 <MySection bgColor="bg-gray">
    <MediaObject heading="today's rates!" />
    <MediaObject heading="some other heading" />
    <MediaObject heading="other other heading" />
 </MySection>

<MySection bgColor="bg-gray">
  <MediaObject heading="today's rates!" />
</MySection>
```

So whatever is written inside the "body" of the component, is passed on as `this.props.children`.

Regarding VSCode yelling at you about the apostrophe is that you were closing the apostrophe before the string end:

```
heading={'today's rates!'}
```

If you use a single quote inside a string, use double quotes:

```
heading={"today's rates!"}
```

or, you can escape the quote:

```
heading={'today\'s rates!'}
```

Comment: Great explanation! You learn something new every day :) Also found this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) which might be helpful to the OP.